# How to convert a linked list of strings into an array of characters in C?

Tags: c, arrays, string, linked-list

I have the following linked list data structure:

```
struct _node {
    char *text;
    stuct _node *next;
}
```

I want to write a function that converts this linked list into an array of strings with each string being terminated by \n and the whole array terminated by \0.

For example, if the linked list was:

`[first]->[second]->NULL`

then the array should look like this:

`[f][i][r][s][t][\n][s][e][c][o][n][d][\n][\0]`

Here is my attempt:

```
char *convertToArray(struct _node *head){
    assert(head != NULL);

    int lines = findLines(head);
    int i = 0;
    struct _node *curr = head;

    char *textBufferArray = NULL; // return NULL if lines == 0
    textBufferArray = malloc(charCount(head) + lines + 1);
    // malloc enough memory for all characters and \n and \0 characters

    if (lines > 0){
        while (curr->next != NULL){
            strlcpy(textBufferArray[i], curr->text, strlen(curr->text)+1);
            // I need to add a new line here
            curr = curr->next;
            i++;
        }
    }

    I need to add \0 before returning
    textBufferArray[charCount(head) + lines] = '\0';

    return textBufferArray;
}
```

Comment: why don't you use a char pointer to array to store each string

Comment: Curious, why the `sizeof(char) *` which is just `1 *`?

Comment: Note that what you are making is not an array of strings. It is an array of characters / one giant string. You may want to clarify your question.

Comment: @RaymondChen True, a _string_ ends with a null character.  OP seems to desire _one_ string.

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: I can't seem to be able to edit the question but yes, it is supposed to be one giant string, i.e. an array of chars.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering you have malloced enough memory it is as simple as this

```
int i=0...
while(cur)
{
   int n =strlen(cur->S),k=0;
   while(n--)
     giant[i++]=cur->S[k++];
   giant[i++]='\n';
   cur=cur->next;
}
giant[i++]='\0';
```